# how to destroy a thread , pause/suspend a thread , resume/runAgain a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progress-bar, media-player

Hey guys
I am using runnable outside the oncreate in my android application where i have used thread to setprogress of ProgressBar. What i dont know is how to stop/destry the thread when stop button is pressed since thread.stop is not a method and how to resume from that , how to even destroy the thread.

I know i have to make some methods and members in runnable but i dont exactly know what??

Comment: Have you thought about using  AsyncTask instead? It has a built-in method for updating a progress indicator and can also be cancelled easily if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.stop()` is no longer used since it was considered dangerous: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html.

You must let the thread come naturally to an end as a result of a variable change. The link also gives some advice about how to achieve this.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private boolean threadDone = false;

    public void done() {
        threadDone = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!threadDone) {
            // work here
            // modify common data
        }
    }
```

}

Warning: make sure you either use a [guarded block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) in the looping code, a method that blocks itself, or a `Thread.sleep(..)`. Thread.sleep is the most primitive of these if you don't understand guarded blocks, but it will work. You could also wait forever and use the interrupt mechanism to cancel the thread which is thrown as `InterruptedException` in the try-catch block when you use a wait or sleep. For this, use `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` as the loop guard condition, then use your Thread object and call `thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html This link is broken

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options and they depend on how you define the various states of your thread.

A thread is effectively stoped when it exits the run() method.

To "pause" and "resume" a thread's execution you can can use wait() and notify().

To illustrate this, here's a quick example:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private boolean keepRunning = false;
    private boolean isPaused = false;

    public void run() {
        keepRunning = true;
        try {
            while (keepRunning) {
                // do stuff here
                if (isPaused) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        // wait for resume() to be called
                        wait();
                        isPaused = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    // note that as-is this won't do anything to a paused thread until
    // it is resumed.
    public void stop() {
        keepRunning = false;

    }

    public void pause() {
        isPaused = true;
    }

    public synchronized void resume() {
        // notify anybody waiting on "this"
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind on the above code: the pause() and stop() methods are non blocking calls so they return immediately.  You can make them blocking calls by using wait and notify.  Also depending on what you do inside your main loop, the thread may never actually pause or stop. This is a common bug in beginner's implementations of socket servers that don't have a timeout set on socket.accept.

Comment: i dont think this is the right way to call notify because i get this error  ->  03-22 14:17:53.328: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2628): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
03-22 14:17:53.328: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2628):     at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)

Comment: are you calling notify() from within a synchronized method or synchronized block?  If not, you will get that message.

Answer (score 2):

To control a Java thread, you should add methods to the object that can be called by other objects which set variables read by your `run()` method. You don't give much information on exactly what you're doing, but here's a possible pattern:

```
public class ProgressBarUpdater implements Runnable{
    private volatile boolean paused = false;
    private volatile boolean finished = false;

    /* other fields, constructor etc. */

    public void run(){
        while(!finished){
            updateProgressBar();

            while(paused && !finished){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000); //Busy wait - should really use wait/notify, but that's another lesson
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pauseProgressBar(){
        paused = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unPauseProgressBar(){
        paused = false;
        //call notify() here when you switch to wait/notify.
    }

    public void stopProgressBar(){
        finished = true;
        //call notify() here too.
    }
}
```

You will probably want to use more robust synchronisation around the control variables, and, as mentioned in the comments, wait/notify rather than a busy wait.

Use as so:

```
ProgressBarUpdater pbu = new ProgressBarUpdater();

Thread t = new Thread(pbu);

t.start();
Thread.sleep(10000); //let the progress bar run for ten seconds.

pbu.pauseProgressBar();
Thread.sleep(10000); //pause it for ten seconds.

pbu.unPauseProgressBar();
Thread.sleep(10000); //restart for another ten seconds.

pbu.stopProgressBar(); //stop progress bar.
```

Comment: hey thanks for the support but when i am trying to stop the thread with your code i get 03-22 14:17:53.328: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2628): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
03-22 14:17:53.328: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2628):     at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
  error

Answer (score 0):

Have the other thread check a boolean flag (isCancelled, or something like that) periodically. Initially is is false.

From your stop button code, set this value to true.

When your thread next checks the flag and finds it to be true, the thread should kill itself.

Comment: calling `interrupt()` from outside and then checking with `isInterrupted()` works just as well as setting your own flag. Plus it has the advantage that it will wake up a sleeping thread so it can end promptly.

Comment: @Ted - I have hitherto been under the impression that it's possible for a thread to be interrupted arbitrarily (which would make this method unsafe) - am I mistaken?

Comment: you are mistaken.  `Thread.interrupt()` won't interrupt a thread arbitrarily.  In fact, it *only* interrupts *some* blocking library calls.  For the rest, it just sets a flag.

Comment: i have only one thread running and in my stop button on click listener i am calling the method of the thread class which sets the flag and it is not working the thread keeps running, then i even added notify in that method of thread even then it keeps on running.